# Will quotes written in my self-published book fall under fair use category?

Tags: copyright

I hold an M.S. in Counseling Psychology and have decided to start writing workbook journals to help people with anxiety, depression, isolation, and various other challenges that people face.

...To do this, I'd like to use one quote per day (for a 4 week workbook/journal) from a different online blog source. The excerpt of text will be brief and start off with "Did you know?..." I will write my own idea, such as "Did you know that exercise can improve your romantic life?" and then provide a small portion (15-25 word excerpt) of a very large blog to educate those who purchase my self-help workbook.

In addition, I will write my own guided questions that relate to therapy to help my readers along their journey back to good mental health (the text/excerpt that I pull from the blog will have nothing to do with the original author's purpose or motive). In addition, I will provide "Enjoy Your Day" activities and self-evaluations of the readers progress...that are entirely mine...info that I learned in grad school as well as other therapists.  This is definitely "my work" and will not reflect the intent of the author of the source that I quote in any way.

I will be quoting my sources in my self-help workbook/journal and those who read my book can look up the entire article that I pulled the quote from. I will provide a full reference, including the URL address.

Since I have 28 quotes (pulled excerpts of text), I can't imagine getting permission from each article or blog post -- yes, they are copywriter and 'curret' in today's world.

My intent is to publish on Amazon KDP.

I did contact one source to seek permission and they found it odd that I would ask them. They said that it's normal to just quote the source and provide the reference...but they would check with higher management.

...this source also brought up a very good point. She indicated that 28 sources is A LOT and that she'd 'make sure' that I am required by law to get permission before making all of those contacts.

Eeringon the 'side of caution' could cause me to not trouble myself to write the workbook because I will only be charging $7.99 and Amazon KDP will be getting most of the money -- I may earn $1.97 per book??

Any thoughts?